# I can't resend a texturepack request

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I code currently a minecraft java plugin which loads a texturepack but I have a problem. When you decline the download of the texturepack, it will never ask again for downloading or accepting and I never got a error.

I used this code:

```
player.setResourcepack("<url>");
```

and it showed one time so it does work but never ask again if I decline it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is expected behavior.
If a player decline resourcepack installation once then he will never receive an installation request again.

https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html#setResourcePack(java.lang.String)

Comment: but many Servers are reasking if i decline. Also some plugins does this to. I also tryed to analyse the code from one plugin wich can reask and found nothing. It uses the exact same code player.setResourcepack("<url>");

Comment: @DAOCMINECRAFT probably it's possible using NMS and packet sending of the resourcepack request. The easiest way is just kick player in case of declined request.
See [PlayerResourcePackStatusEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/event/player/PlayerResourcePackStatusEvent.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try to provide a new version of the texture pack or rename the texture pack. As a result the players should receive a new request.

Answer (score 1):

You can send packages and listen to the responses. There are many ways to do so. Essentially, you have to send a `PacketPlayOutResourcePackSend` packet with the necessary information.

Afterwards, listen to the `PacketPlayInResourcePackStatus`. There are just a few possible states: `SUCCESSFULLY_LOADED, DECLINED, FAILED_DOWNLOAD, ACCEPTED`. In theory, you have to resend the package request once the state is `DECLINED`. *(Like my credit card -.-)*

I can't give you any more details since I haven't used this in a while, but no one else seemed to answer your question.